# How to Animate iPhone New Screen towards Left

Tags: iphone, animation

I am new bee in iPhone and just started development in it.

Learning a lot because of friends like you!

I just learnt how to go to another screen from current screen and i Did well due to tutorials from Internet.

But now the problem is when new screen comes up it animates from Bottom to Up and when we click DONE button to close the screen it goes from Up to Down. I have seen many applications in iPhone that animate the new screen from Right to Left and again from Left to Right.

What Piece of code do i need to add into the following to animate it toward left.
Please guide me Friends

```
MainScreen *screen = [[MainScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 self.mainScreen = screen;

 [self presentModalViewController:mainScreen animated:YES];
```

Comment: Do you have Navigation controller based app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four different ModelTransitionsFor View Controllers.

You can set those for

```
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

There are 3 other Styles you can check on [Apple Site Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle)

---

If you need to do something like Navigation Style. you need to push your view controller to navigation stack.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

Comment: since The First code snippet is not working on my side. and Now i have learnt from you that i need to use navigationController stack for that purpose. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:yourView animated:YES];
```

use this

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Navigation based app then replace code with below.

```
MainScreen *screen = [[MainScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.mainScreen = screen;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few modal view transitional styles available. [Check apples](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle) documentation on this.

Also there are few uiviewtransitionanimation styles also described neatly in [apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).